# Advanced Search gives different dataset than same search in Reports

Tags: civireport

When I use the Advanced Search or Search Builder to select a dataset the returned contacts are correct. If I do the same search using in CiviReport with the same search criteria one contact is displayed twice. If from the advanced search I create a smart group the group contains the correct number of contacts. If I then use CiviReport and search using the smart group one of the contacts is shown twice.

I have looked at the database to see if I can understand what might be causing this without success. It is possible that it has happened after merging the erroneous contact but I am not certain.

Answer (score 3):

Advanced Search and Search Builder produce a list of Contacts. But a report can pull data other than Contacts and the Group By in the report can be such that you can get a Contact more than once in your output. For example when pulling a Membership or a Contribution Report.

For a Constituent Report if you're seeing the Contacts more than once: hit the checkbox for Contact ID (under Columns) - to confirm these are the same contacts in your CiviCRM database. If the Contact IDs are different - then go and merge them. If Contact IDs are the same then you are likely selecting a column that a contact has more than one bit of data for.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense to me. If I report by selecting a smart group shouldn't the report contain what's in the smart group and nothing else? Even when I remove the Group By in the report the result is the same. Where do I look to find out why a contact is included more than once?

Comment: No - not necessarily - it could be that you're looking at eg Memberships or Donations for all contacts in your Smart Group. What specifc report template are you using?

Comment: I am using the template Constituent Report - Summary. There are only two contact records that are shown twice and I cannot see what is different about these contacts for them to be treated differently from the other 145 contacts in the particular dataset.

Comment: Updated my Answer above. So look to see if the contacts that are show twice have multiple (primary) phone numbers or addresses - depending on what columns you pull

Comment: Hi Karen - many thanks for your persistence in assisting me. The cause was a duplicate Home Address in the contact record and once that was resolved the results were as I expected.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear.